# How to send mails through smtp in c#

Tags: c#

How to send mails through smtp in c#

Comment: Little effort, vague and duplicated question. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+send+mails+through+smtp+in+c%23

Comment: Use the search box in the upper right corner of this site. Keywords: `mail`, `c#`, `smtpclient`. Putting the same in the google search box will also yield results.

Comment: stackuser3, you seriously need to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 3):

System.Net.Mail.MailMessage in conjunction with System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("from address");
mail.Subject = "subject";
mail.Body = "body";
mail.IsBodyHtml = IsHtml;
mail.To.Add("targetaddress");

SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtphost");
mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

try
{
    mailClient.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    mailClient = null;
}
```

Comment: Your namespace reference is wrong. It is System.Net.Mail.MailMessage, not System.Net.MailMessage

Comment: both MailMessage and SmtpClient(4.0) implement idisposable. calling dispose is essential.

Answer (score 2):

You use the [`System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class to create the message.

Then send it using the [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to do the actual sending.

There are examples in the linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) reference. It should be what you are looking for