# Open gmail inbox in c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, gmail

I want to open my gmail inbox in C# code.I will give my gmail username and password. It should open my inbox automatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide some more info on what you are looking for.  Are you looking to see the web view similar to your browser, or are you looking for an email type program interface similar to Thunderbird or Outlook

Comment: Really thanks for your reply,i want to make a gmail desktop app using c#.net ,for that i want to access my original inbox to my app,how to do that, Thank you

Comment: Start looking here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/ (and apart of that, a search engine is a really powerful tool!).

Comment: Basically you are trying to create your own email client, but why?  There are so many others out there.  You need to decide what you want to do?  IMAP, POP, or just display the gmail web page in your app.  This is too broad to be answered here, I think

Comment: but i need to create like that,i just want to know what the operation is going on,so please help me on that ...

Answer (score 1):

As many of the comments above have said, Gmail has many existing APIs for accessing it https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/. There are many libraries available for accessing these APIs, including previous questions on stackoverflow like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544895/imap-library-for-net and [How to send mails through smtp in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536850/how-to-send-mails-through-smtp-in-c-sharp).